# Spring response OutputStream in another window

Tags: html, http, spring-mvc, servlets, outputstream

I have a Spring MVC controller that generates a PDF

```
...
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");                                 
final OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(pdfService.generateApplicationReport(device));
out.flush();
out.close();
return null;
...
```

I generate the print using a submit button

```
<button id="pdfId" class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Print</button>
```

But I would like to generate it in another browser window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't write it to a new window or anything from the server side, you can instruct the client to open a link that loads the pdf in a new window with JavaScript.

EG:

```
<a href='somesite.com/endpoint/your_pdf_servlet_thing' target='_blank'>
```

Where accessing the link there would load the PDF in the browser for the client.